# Setting start levels for dynamic Eclipse features: alternatives to p2.inf?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, p2

I have an Eclipse-based OSGi application consisting of bundles organised in features. I use a product definition to launch the application. In this definition, I can also set start-levels for my bundles.

Now imagine I want to add a feature to the running application. Is a p2.inf file the only way to specify start levels for the bundles in this feature? Re-defining and re-starting the product does not sound like an optimal solution as it's not really dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-starting the product"? p2 should allow you to install new versions of the running product - AFAIK a re-start is not required.

Comment: That's a good hint, thanks. This means we could the following:

1. create a new version of our product containing the start-levels for the new bundles to be installed.
2. install this product version.
3. add the new feature to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any real tooling support for setting start levels for bundles on the feature level. The only option you have is manual hacking with a p2.inf.

I think the reason that setting start levels is only really supported for products is that p2 can't handle the case where start levels are specified multiple times. This could easily happen if setting start levels on feature level was encouraged.

So, you can make this work on feature level, but only if you know what you do.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem I believe: I have a feature that is both part of a packaged product and present on an update site to be installed into an Eclipse IDE. And I also want to set the start-level for some of the plug-ins to ensure a very early start-up.

I have overcome this with a `p2.inf` file with the following content:

```
instructions.configure=setStartLevel(startLevel:1);markStarted(started: true);
instructions.unconfigure=setStartLevel(startLevel:-1);markStarted(started: false);
```

(I don't think I need to specify the start-level in the product definition anymore though I have not tried to remove this yet.)

I originally used start-level 2, but at least for Juno packages, there are some plug-ins that are started at level 1 so I now use level 1 as well.

Comment: I just tried to remove the start-level spec from the product, but it does not seem to work properly - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17532669/796559